# How To Determine If Image Is URI Or Thumbnail In JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, uri, thumbnails

I have a web service for image processing like this:
http://test.com/image-url?http://someimage.jpg

The problem is when i retrieve images from Google Images, they are returning either
**URI**: data:image/jpeg;base64,/
OR
**Thumbnail**: http://t2.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTwwtBgTsExgE2WP

How can i determine if the image url is URI or thumbnail using JavaScript since my web service only work on real image?

PS: I do realize some image URL might be like this: test.com/images=12345

Answer (score 2):

```
if (urlToImage.indexOf('data:image/') == 0) {
    // URI
} else {
    // thumbnail
}
```

- if your urlToImage has 'data:image/' at the beginning of it, than it's an URI else thumbnail.

Comment: Hai Greg thanks for your quick answer.
If the url is http://test.jpg i assume your code will go to thumbnail?

Comment: Yes, it will. Since it does not have 'data:image/' at the beginning of it. If you would like only to accept images with a full url, you should use a regexp.

Comment: Something like
if (/(https?:\/\/)?(www\.)?([a-zA-Z0-9_%]*)\b\.[a-z]{2,4}(\.[a-z]{2})?((\/[a-zA-Z0-9_%]*)+)?(\.[a-z]*)?(\?([a-zA-Z0-9_%]*)+)?/g.test(urlToImage)) {
    // thumbnail
} else if (urlToImage.indexOf('data:image/') == 0) {
    // URI
} else {
    // none of the above
}

Comment: You can test and create your regexps here: http://gskinner.com/RegExr/ the regexp I posted does not require the image to end in jpg.